# React router direct links not working on Azure Web App Linux

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, azure-web-app-service, azure-linux

I've developed an PoC about PWA (Progressive Web Apps) using ReactJs to show how to use camera, geolocation, microphone, light sensors and etc from Browser API.

I've created a route for each feature in this web app and everything works fine in localhost. But when I deploy the npm build version of my react app on **Azure Wep App Linux service** it don't work properly. I can access the main page (index.html) and from there I can navigate to any other page, but when I try access any route direct form its url I receive an 404 error. Except from index page all urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually.

Ex:
https://pwa.mypoc.dev/ ***-- Works fine***
https://pwa.mypoc.dev/lights ***-- Do Not Work***

I'v used this command on azure "Settings" > "General settings" > "Startup Command":

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/build --no-daemon
```

I've found a question related to it but the answer did not help me, as I'm not using `web.config` because it is a **Linux machine running Node 10 LTS**:  [React App not starting in azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624277/react-app-not-starting-in-azure-app-service)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After a little more research I found the problem. As Linux Azure Web Apps uses pm2 to serve a node app I found the answer looking into the official documentation.

> PM2 is a daemon process manager that will help you manage and keep your application online. Getting started with PM2 is straightforward, it is offered as a simple and intuitive CLI, installable via NPM.

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#serving-spa-redirect-all-to-indexhtml

Just need to add the `--spa` option into the *Startup Command* on **Azure Web Apps Linux** *General Settings*:

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/build --no-daemon --spa
```

Using `--spa` option pm2 will automatically redirect all queries to the index.html and then react router will do its magic.

Comment: is there a way to pull it off without PM2? does anyone know if linux web app respects htaccess or something?

Comment: Don't know for sure. But I belive that its not possible, as the linux web app is a PaaS solution. You could try to use web app container to try it without PM2.

Comment: I am facing same issue for next js app on azure linux web app and ny adding above as startup command still have same issue

Comment: Have you change `/home/site/wwwroot/build` for the path to your main file?

Comment: I have been looking all over the place until I find this thread! Solved my hands..

Answer (score 0):

This below startup command is working fine.

But this is from "Settings" -> Configuration -> "General settings" -> "Startup Command":

pm2 serve build --no-daemon --spa